# what happens generally when configured for rx or tx uart interrupt mode?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, uart

when i configure receive or transmit  over uart in  interrupt mode , how does the signal get triggered if data is received or to be transmitted. Since nvic is present is it memory mapped and change of signal triggers the interrupt , please explain.

Answer (score 0):

No, interrupts are not transmitted from the peripheral to the interrupt controller through memory mapping.

There is a line on the silicon which goes from the peripheral to the NVIC separately from the bus matrix.  The processor core has no view of this signal directly.  It can only read the register interface of the peripheral or NVIC and execute an exception when the NVIC tells it to.